# ContentView with Own and Given Content

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nested, contentview

In an app I have two `ContentView` controls I am trying to compose within a top-level `ContentPage`.  The first, `ScaffoldView`, contains some layout elements I want to have throughout the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.ScaffoldView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid
            Margin="10,35,10,10"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Awesome header stuff -->
            <!-- I'd like the below to take given content -->
            <ContentView
                Grid.Row="..."
                Content="{Binding Content}" />
            <!-- Even more awesome footer stuff -->
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The second, `InputsView`, just has a few pairs of `Label`/`Entry` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.InputsView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Label1"
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Entry Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Input1"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="Label2"
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Entry Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Input2"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="Label3"
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Entry Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Input3"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Finally, the top-level `ContentPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App"
             x:Class="App.MainPage">
    <controls:ScaffoldView>
        <controls:InputsView />
    </controls:ScaffoldView>
</ContentPage>
```

Currently, all that shows is the `InputsView`.  I suppose this is just because the entire `Content` of the `MainPage` is taken up with the `ScaffoldView`, and the entire `Content` of the `ScaffoldView` as defined in `Scaffold.xaml` is overridden by the `<controls:InputsView />` tag.

Ideally, I'd like there to be some way of including `<controls:InputsView />` inside the opening and closing `<controls:ScaffoldView>` tags as above, and it show this given content within the `ScaffoldView`'s own content defined within `Scaffold.xaml`.

Is it possible to nest/mix `Content` this way, or will I need to define a custom property, e.g. `ChildContent`?

Comment: It will show the Content property of `ScaffoldView`, in your case it is `InputsView` since you have overridden the already defined one (inside your ScaffoldView.xaml) when you consumed (by nesting). by default nesting a ContentView = assign it Content property.

Comment: do you require nesting like you described or you are flexible?

Comment: I can be flexible, though for the sake of databinding it might be better if it was nested.  I think I might try looking at what `StackLayout` does with its `Children` property.

Comment: @Bondolin It seems that [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter) using ContentPresenter  can help you.